# SQL treat two entries as one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with `stock codes` and `quantity sold`, but I would like to treat 2 different stock codes as one, the reason being is that one is imported and the other one locally produced but are the same product, 
lets say

```
Product A - Imported, Stock code is abc123
Product A - Local, Stock code is aimp563
```

I want to sum over the `quantity sold` but treat the same product with and an `imported stock code` and `local stock code` as one. Is this possible?

Okay this is what I have
tbe table looks like

```
Product              | StockCode  | QtySold
Product A - Local    | prdA001loc | 100
Product A - Imported | prdAImp7Z4 | 150

SELECT Product, SUM(QtySold) FROM tblA GROUP BY StockCode, Product
```

But this will just return the table as is. I would like this output:

```
Product        | QtySold
Product A      | 250
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried already? Can you show us your query?

Comment: Without your schema, how on earth do you suppose we can help you?

Comment: By specifying `sql` and `microsoft` as your tags - did you mean that you're using **SQL Server**, or are you using **MS Access** with SQL ?? Please add the relevant product-specific tag to your question!

Comment: @ marc_S Just SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to update your DB schema to have reflect this information however if you need some naive solution you can use the following statement

```
SELECT substring(product,  1  , charindex('-',product)), SUM(QtySold) 
FROM tblA GROUP BY substring(product,  1  , charindex('-',product))
```

note that the above statement assuming that all your products name will be similar to what is mentioned inside your question

Comment: Thanks however this won't work because the names do differ and sometime Import is written as Imp, and may be in the middle of the name

Comment: Tha's why I told you you need to do changes in the DB schema or maybe use the [Reporting database pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ReportingDatabase.html) to resolve this situation